# How to play any HLS stream url in chromecast?

Tags: ios, chromecast

Interested in the question m3u8-play video streams on chromecast device. Studying the docks as I understand it does not necessarily write Custom Receiver, ready enough to use Default Receiver or Styled Media Receiver. But some servers with HLS videos have the problem with CORS.
What are the options to solve this problem to play any m3u8-streams (from any server)?
Use CORS-proxy or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot get around the CORS requirement so your options are limited; the proxy approach seems to be your only option. Note that your options are the same regardless of using a custom receiver or a default/styled; even if you write a custom receiver, you will run into the very same CORS requirement.

Comment: Please tell me where to find the cors-proxy for m3u8 playing.
http://www.corsproxy.com/  is often not available.